# In zsh vim mode, when replacing multiple characters, backspace does not work as expected

Tags: bash, zsh, vim, replace

I want to do the following: In the console, in `vim` mode, replace several characters (vim command `R`), while being able to revert the changes with backspace. In `bash` it works the same as in `vim`:

```
bash
set -o vi
echo "foo bar" <ESC>
```

Now move back to say "f" with vim commands, e.g. `Ff`, then `R` to replace multiple characters. I can now write e.g. `bar foo`, then I get

```
echo "bar foo"
```

And now press BACKSPACE e.g. three times, then I see

```
echo "bar bar"
```

That's the behaviour I want, it's the same as in `vim`. However, in `zsh`, I can try similarly:

```
zsh
bindkey -v
echo "foo bar" <ESC>
```

Do the same thing as above, but end with:

```
echo "bar "
```

In short: The behaviour of replacing multiple characters in `zsh` is not working as expected when using BACKSPACE. Instead of reverting the character to what it was before, it is simply deleted.

How can I get the same behaviour in `zsh` as in `vim`?

Comment: Note that these are _not_ VIM modes.  They are vi modes.  vi is not synonymous with VIM.

Comment: Note that that default behaviour of `zsh` (zle) matches that of `tcsh` or `dash` (libedit).